# Apache2 RewriteEngine causing 403 Error

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2, httpd.conf, http-status-code-403

I used the following config on apache2 conf file

"

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

"

so that I would be able to remove the ".html" suffix after my links. This worked fine but when I enter the domain by itself without extensions it will give me a 403 forbidden error.... but If I type in /index after the domain it will continue fine. What can be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: when you add the `.html`, you are referring to a file,  so the condition would not met and the rule will not apply.

Comment: so what shall be done to make the home page launch by itself when a person enters the domain ? can the rule be modified and to what ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to solve my issue:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```